# Yii2 "has many" relation returns only first row

Tags: php, yii2

The model `Person` has has-many relation to `PersonType`:

```
public function getPersonTypes()    
{
    return $this->hasMany(PersonType::className(), ['PersonID' => 'PersonID']);
}
```

I need to show in view all PersonType's related values.

Model Person:

```
public function ListPersonTypes()
{            
    $data = $this->getPersonTypes()->all();    
    $list = array();
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        $list[] = $value['PersonTypeName'];
        return implode(', ', $list);   
    }
}
```

But, why `ListPersonTypes()` returns only first row from table `PersonType`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that in your code you are running just one iteration... as you call a return inside the foreach.

```
public function ListPersonTypes()
{    
    $data = $this->getPersonTypes()->all();   
    $list = array();
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        $list[] = $value['PersonTypeName'];
    }
    return implode(', ', $list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function ListPersonTypes()
{

    $data=$this->getPersonTypes;

    $list=array();
    foreach ($data as $value){
        $list[]=$value['PersonTypeName'];
        return implode(',',$list);

    }
}
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

- you don't use it  correctly `$this->getPersonTypes()->all();`  use
  this  `$this->personTypes`
- write the return out of the loop

Yii2  (gii) by default create this functions for you access  that like a attribute of model  and return as arrray .

This function hasnt be creates  to access as a function literal .

Try this code

```
public function ListPersonTypes()
    {
        // this go to function getPersonTypes and return a array of them
        $data=$this->personTypes;

        $list=array();
        foreach ($data as $value){
            $list[]=$value['PersonTypeName'];            
        }
      return implode(',',$list);
    }
```